# pass & in query string parameter in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a string that contain & like hobbies & interest. Query string parameter showing it as two parameters. How can I fix this

**parameter:** hobbies

**interest :**

I want this to string rather two separate parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string which could potentially contain URL-meaningful characters should be [encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) with `encodeURIComponent`.  For example:

```js
let value = 'this&that';
let url = `/some/url?value=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
console.log(url);
```

Server-side code generally decodes this automatically.  (Though I suppose it's not guaranteed, someone may be running a custom home-grown web server or something like that for example.)